# Broken link on img component

Tags: html, css

I have this responsive page:
http://attractivebohemianglass.com/

In mobile version, link on logo become disfunctional. Code is still the same, I didnt find any difference.
Do you know where is the problem? Thanks for answers.

Comment: I tried look at the code and made any changes, but nothing happend.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, novice here.

And any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of positioning, another div is positioned above the logo element and the div that is positioned above the logo has a bigger z-index (thats how its specified which layer will be above or below).

Usualy this is the problem in this kind of cases, have had this kind of issues myself and this was the problem.

Just found out which is the div with the problem which covers the logo in mobile view, its the div with this class `shopping_cart`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div#header_logo {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: please add a description as to how this answers the question, recommend reading [answer]